# mongoose set default model / schema value as null

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

How to set a schema's key / value to `null`?

```
var TheModelSchema = new Schema({
  someNullKey: null, // is this possible?
  someDate: Date,
  someString: String,
})
```

Docs looked at:

- http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html

Other questions looked at:

- [Mongoose set default as empty object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29188131/mongoose-set-default-as-empty-object)
- [Is better use an empty value as a '' or as NULL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542065/is-better-use-an-empty-value-as-a-or-as-null)
- [mongoose custom schema types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18859284/mongoose-custom-schema-types)
- [MongoDB empty string value vs null value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18606323/mongodb-empty-string-value-vs-null-value)
- [Mongoose set default as empty object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29188131/mongoose-set-default-as-empty-object)
- [Mongoose Schema Embedded Document Default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31092479/mongoose-schema-embedded-document-default)

Comment: What the sense? BTW define it as `{type:String, default: null}`

Comment: @Michelem Great thanks. I am going with `{type: Boolean, default: null}`. The endpoint I am trying to hit is asking for `null` and is suppose to return a boolean. Not sure what the  sense. Your comment is an answer, I would like to accept. I had a hard time googling for an answer to this.